# Adaboost + SVM vs GBM + hange function of SVM

Tags: machine-learning, svm

We know that SVM is equivalent to the `hange loss function`:
$$\min\limits_{w,b}\ \Big(1 - y(w\cdot x + b)\Big)^+ + \lambda||w||^2.$$

Then there are two ways of classification boosting based on SVM:

1. AdaBoost with weaker learner SVM;
2. GBM with weak learner SVM (the gradient of hange loss function).

First, I believe that AdaBoost is not a special case of GBM (AdaBoost is not to fit the negative gradient of loss function).

Then is there any relation between above two algrithms or which one is better?

Comment: This is a nice question. I think you might want to use the full form of  GBM as Gradient Boosting. It may be confused with the General Boltzmann Machine. But it is clear from the context. But being clear is helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me, these two are different boosting mechanisms. Gradient boosting utilizes the pseudo-residuals or the gradient of the loss function being minimized to train subsequent models. On the other hand, AdaBoost works by training subsequent models giving more importance to misclassified samples.
I haven't found my theoretical comparison between them, but different empirical studies reported that Gradient boosting is better. [**paper link**](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-981-15-0633-8_22)